# Как проверить работоспособность сервиса WCF при хостинге

Tags: c#, wcf

Как можно проверить работоспособность сервиса при хостинге? Я пишу что-то типа:

```
using (var host =  new ServiceHost(typeof(Servie)))
{
    host.Open();
}
```

Но по факту ведь сервис создается при обращении к нему? И если сервис был неправильно сконфигурирован (нет каких-то файлов, или еще что), все ошибки полетят на клиент.

Хотелось бы как-то проверить, что сервис правильно сконфигурирован и готов к работе. Как это можно сделать? Создать его вручную перед хостингом? Или я что-то неправильно понимаю?

Comment: _"Создать его вручную перед хостингом?"_ -- да. пишете тесты и проверяете работу сервиса. тест - это может быть отдельный проект-клиент сервиса. в VS есть шаблоны проектов для тестирования.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы проверить работоспособность сервиса, я написал класс-тест, который пытается получить **wsdl-сервиса**.
 **Если удалось получить корректный wsdl, значит сервис работает**. 
Главная функция этого класса - функция получение wsdl сервиса. Чтобы получить wsdl, я нашел функцию(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.aspx)

```
private static MetadataSet GetMetadataSet(string url)
{
            MetadataExchangeClientMode mode = MetadataExchangeClientMode.MetadataExchange;
            int maxReceivedMessageSize = 3000000;
            Uri address = new Uri(url);

            Binding mexBinding = null;
            if (string.Compare(address.Scheme, "http", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                mexBinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding();
            else if (string.Compare(address.Scheme, "https", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                mexBinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpsBinding();
            else if (string.Compare(address.Scheme, "net.tcp", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                mexBinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding();
            else if (string.Compare(address.Scheme, "net.pipe", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                mexBinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexNamedPipeBinding();
            else
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Not supported schema '{0}' for metadata exchange"));

            if (mexBinding is WSHttpBinding)
            {
                (mexBinding as WSHttpBinding).MaxReceivedMessageSize = maxReceivedMessageSize;
                mode = MetadataExchangeClientMode.HttpGet;
            }
            else if (mexBinding is CustomBinding)
                (mexBinding as CustomBinding).Elements.Find<TransportBindingElement>().MaxReceivedMessageSize = maxReceivedMessageSize;
            else
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Not supported binding for metadata exchange"));

            MetadataExchangeClient proxy = new MetadataExchangeClient(mexBinding);
            proxy.ResolveMetadataReferences = true;
            MetadataSet mds = proxy.GetMetadata(address, mode);
            return mds;
}
```

Чтобы была возможность получить wsdl от сервиса, я открываю для всех сервисов конечную точку [mex](http://wcftutorial.net/metadata-exchange-endpoint.aspx).